# XCode 9 - Fail to archive app

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode9.1

I was using XCode 7.3 and recently migrate to XCode 9.1.

Since, there is no problem to launch app on mobile (compile, run without crashes).

But when I want to archive app, it fail with this error : `"No such module 'RealmSwift'"` or `"No such module 'ObjectMapper'"`

I'm using Pods :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

def pods
platform :ios, '11.1'
pod 'RESideMenu', '4.0.7'
pod 'Alamofire', '4.6.0'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '3.3.0'
pod 'JSONHelper', '2.2.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 3.1'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.0'
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.0'
pod 'KVNProgress', '2.3'
pod "CalendarLib", '2.0'
pod 'Charts', '3.0.4'
pod 'SwiftEventBus', :tag => '2.2.0', :git => 'https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus.git'
pod "RichEditorView", :branch => 'swift-4', :git => 'https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView.git'
pod 'SwiftHSVColorPicker'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
    end
  end
end

target 'target1' do
    pods
end

target 'target2' do
    pods
end
```

**EDIT**

I found the bug ! 
When I archive with **arm64, armv7 and armv7s** it fail, but if I archive with only arm64 this is a success... But on devices below iPhone 5s, app is not compatible !! 
Is there a way to fix ?

Comment: Remove all the version numbers from pod except carthage and update all pods and then try to archive followed by cleaning your project and driveddata

Comment: Remove pod from your project, Update your cocoa Pod and again add pod in your project (Remove all the version numbers from pod as suggested by dahiya_boy)

Comment: Do not works...

Comment: Please see my edit